# Spring Data JPA Repository to refresh cache after Save()

Tags: spring, caching, spring-data-jpa

We are having a Student Entity, and implemented cache. We perform insert record only when record not found in database.

It works fine first time, as record doesn't exist in DB. But, second time if we re-submit same request then it fetch student Entity from cache and return null. (In DB, it exist) and hence try to re-insert that data and fails with unique constrain.

Can someone help, how to clear/update cache in this case.

**Repository Code Snippet:**

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames="StudentCache", cacheManager="DepartmentCacheManager", sync=true)
    Student findByStudentId(String StudentId);
}
```

**Service Code Snippet**

```
Student student = studentRepository.findByStudentId(studentId);
if (student == null) {
    student= createStudentObject(studentId);
    studentRepository.save(student);
}
```

Comment: I am not clear with this statement " But, second time if we re-submit same request then it fetch student Entity from cache and return null" why is it returning null if its already in the database so in cache as well ??

Comment: In find method, we have explicitly told to use different cache. Hibernate use it's own cache during save instead of cache which I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unless` to specify do not cache the result if it is null , but it does not work with [sync=true](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#sync--)

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames="StudentCache", cacheManager="DepartmentCacheManager", unless="#result == null")
    Student findByStudentId(String StudentId);
}
```

If you must use `sync` , you can consider to use `@CachePut` to update the cache after saving the student.

```
public class StudentRepository{

    @CachePut(cacheNames="StudentCache", cacheManager="DepartmentCacheManager",key="#student.studentId")
    public Student save(Student student){

    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear you solve the problem. So now please consider to accept my answer and give my answer a vote up :D

Comment: What will happen if multiple thread will try to update same cache variable? Will it fail ?